# Get meta description from external website

Tags: python, django

I need to extract the meta description of an external website. I've already searched and maybe the simple answer is already out there, but I wasn't able to apply it to my code.

Currently I can get it's title doing the following:

```
external_sites_html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(external_sites_html)
title = soup.title.string
```

However, the description is a bit trickier. It can come in the form of:

```
<meta name="og:description" content="blabla"
<meta property="og:description" content="blabla"
<meta name="description" content="blabla"
```

So what I want is to extract the first one of these that appears inside the html. It'll then be added to the database as:

```
entry.description = extracted_desc
entry.save
```

If it doesn't find any description at all, then it just proceeds saving only the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `find` method on the soup object and find the tags with specific attributes. Here we need to find the `meta` tag with either `name` attribute equal to `og:description` or `description` or `property` attribute equal to `description`.

```
# First get the meta description tag
description = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'og:description'}) or soup.find('meta', attrs={'property':'description'}) or soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'description'})

# If description meta tag was found, then get the content attribute and save it to db entry
if description:
    entry.description = description.get('content')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
# Order these in order of preference
description_selectors = [
    {"name": "description"},
    {"name": "og:description"},
    {"property": "description"}
]

for selector in description_selectors:
    description_tag = soup.find(attrs=selector)
    if description_tag and description_tag.get('content'):
        description = description_tag['content']
        break
else:
    desciption = ''
```

Just note, the else is for the `for`, and not for the `if`.